# Android - get list of installed apps signatures

Tags: java, android, security

So, Im using [NIST](https://www.nist.gov/) provided database for android phones to detect malicious applications. The main source/database is looking like this:

```
"SHA-1","MD5","CRC32","FileName","FileSize","ProductCode","OpSystemCode","SpecialCode"
"0000000F8527DCCAB6642252BBCFA1B8072D33EE","68CE322D8A896B6E4E7E3F18339EC85C","E39149E4","Blended_Coolers_Vanilla_NL.png",30439,28948,"358",""
"00000091728653B7D55DF30BFAFE86C52F2F4A59","81AE5D302A0E6D33182CB69ED791181C","5594C3B0","ic_menu_notifications.png",366,31287,"358",""
"0000065F1900120613745CC5E25A57C84624DC2B","AEB7C147EF7B7CEE91807B500A378BA4","24400952","points_program_fragment.xml",1684,31743,"358",""
```

As you can see first column is SHA1 hash code of specific app. My ultimate goal is to **get all installed apps signatures, i.e. SHA1 hash code** to compare them with database and see which apps are harmful.

I spend some time for browsing the net. I came up with solution for my own app:
https://gist.github.com/scottyab/b849701972d57cf9562e
However, this returns **only your app SHA1** hash code.

For example, in this way I can get all application packages names:

```
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

---

***Maybe there is possibility to get all installed apps signatures? Let me know.***

Comment: "My ultimate goal is to get all installed apps signatures, i.e. SHA1 hash code" -- the values in the NIST database are not "signatures". They are "Cryptographic hash values (MD5 and SHA-1) of the file's content", per [the NIST documentation](https://www.nist.gov/software-quality-group/nsrl-introduction). "I came up with solution for my own app" -- that code generates a SHA-1 hash for the public signing key, not a SHA-1 hash of the app.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. So there is possibility to get file's content into SHA1 hash code and compare it to NIST database?

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this:

```
void printSampleSha1List(Context ctx) {

    List<ApplicationInfo> packages = ctx.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    for (int i = 0; i < packages.size(); ++i) {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = null;
        try {
            packageInfo = ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    packages.get(i).packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (packageInfo != null) {
            for (Signature signature : packageInfo.signatures) {
                // SHA1 the signature
                String sha1 = getSHA1(signature.toByteArray());

                Log.i("Sha1", "name:" + packages.get(i).packageName + ", " + sha1);
                //note sample just checks the first signature
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}

public static String getSHA1(byte[] sig) {
    MessageDigest digest = null;
    try {
        digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1", "BC");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    digest.update(sig);
    byte[] hashtext = digest.digest();
    return bytesToHex(hashtext);
}

//util method to convert byte array to hex string
public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    final char[] hexArray = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
            '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    int v;
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
        v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}
```

This will give you a list of SHA1 of signatures of all the packets on the device.

Comment: That code generates a SHA-1 hash for the public signing key, not a SHA-1 hash of the app.

Comment: @CommonsWare so is there any chance to get SHA-1 hash of the apps?